# Should I close a question if it is related to a bug that won't be solved?

Tags: discussion

I made [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44256402/1485885) a time ago, and it happened to be an open issue of Visual Studio. Yesterday, such issue was marked as *Won't fix*. Should I close the question or keep it open in the case someone someday provide a workaround (after a year and a half this question has had very low impact)?

Comment: I would argue that your question is better suited for https://superuser.com/ anyways. I had a question similar in nature about [Adobe Reader](https://superuser.com/q/902758/259665) which has proven to be useful for years.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks! I was dubious about where to post it... as I've found many questions related to developer tools in SO, I thought it would be the correct place (though superuser.com probably would have been good too).

Comment: There's quite a bit of overlap and on-topic questions of years past can easily be considered off-topic nowadays due to the myriad of specialized SE sites so it can be confusing. Notepad++ is a developer tool too but I chose to post my question on Super User https://superuser.com/q/1274554/259665 and it seemed well received. I don't feel too strongly about where your question should go but Super User answers tend to garner more hacky answers I feel.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus OK, thanks for the explanation... do you think it worth publishing it there now that it has been marked as "won't fix" anyway?

Comment: That's really up to you; you can flag your question for moderator attention and request for it's migration. The question seems on-topic for both sites per the existing tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017 and https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017. I'd recommend reading through some of those posts and if you think Super User has a better audience for your tool then it's your call :)

Comment: It isn't actually a true "won't fix" case, they just refused to look at it.  Which *is* somewhat understandable, it works just fine on my 15.5.6 install.  There's another detail that matters that isn't visible, I suspect it might have something to do with the selected UI language.  This does have a knack for being found back some sunny day by someone that figured out the detail.  Be sure to supply some more, like living in Spain.

Comment: It certainly is appropriate for Super User, but you are also right that it's a developer tool and thus explicitly on topic here on SO. I'd wager a guess that the Super User users are more likely to be more ready to answer a question like this had it been answerable, but it's not off topic here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no close reason for, "There is no solution to this problem".  That's an *answer* to the question, not a close reason.  If it's impossible to do what a question asks, then an answer explaining why it's impossible is *an answer*.  If it's impossible because there's a bug, then explaining the documented bug, and stating that the official statement is that it won't be fixed is *an answer*.

Providing alternate solutions to the underlying problem using a different approach would of course also be a valid answer to the question.  Whether or not it's a useful alternative would be determined by votes on it.